# how to draw random points inside an ellipse matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to fill this ellipse with N random points inside it 
any help I'd be glad

```
clear ,close all;
xCenter = 15;
yCenter = 10;
xRadius = 3.5;
yRadius = 8;
theta = 0 : 0.01 : 2*pi;
N = 100; % N rand points

x = xRadius * cos(theta) + xCenter;
y = yRadius * sin(theta) + yCenter;    

plot(x, y, 'LineWidth', 1);

axis square;

grid on;
```

I tried this code to generate 100 points inside the ellipse with specific parameters but I did not achieve my goal,

```
xCenter = 5;
yCenter = 3;
xRadius = 3.5;
yRadius = 8;
theta = 0 : 0.01 : 2*pi;
N = 100;

x = xRadius * cos(theta) + xCenter;
y = yRadius * sin(theta) + yCenter;

xq=(rand(N,1)*(2*yRadius) - yRadius);
yq=(rand(N,1)*(2*yRadius) - yRadius);    

in = inpolygon(xq,yq,x,y);
hold on
inX = xq(in);
inY = yq(in);
outX = xq(~in);
outY = yq(~in);
plot(inX, inY , 'ro');
plot(outX, outY, 'b*');
plot(x, y, 'LineWidth', 1);

axis square;

grid on;
```

Comment: my goal is to plot N random points within the ellipse area

Comment: I will edit the question

Comment: You haven't accepted answers in any of your previous questions. Some of them have very good written answers. Consider revisiting your previous questions and marking the best answers that solve your problem as [accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/) by clicking **`✔`**, on the left side of the answers (only one answer per question can be marked as accepted). You can also [upvote](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/173400/)  the best and all other helpful answers if you like by clicking on **`▲`**, on the left side of the answers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sardar's answer produces points not evenly distributed within the ellipse. This code produces an even distribution of points:

```
xCenter = 15;
yCenter = 10;
xRadius = 3.5;
yRadius = 8;
N = 100;

% Generate points in the ellipse
t = 2*pi * rand(N,1);
d = sqrt(rand(N,1));
x = xCenter + xRadius * d .* cos(t);
y = yCenter + yRadius * d .* sin(t);
plot(x,y,'o')
```

The difference is the `sqrt` on the normalized (0 to 1) distance from the origin `d`. By computing this square root, you increase the density of points closer to the edge of the ellipse. This compensates for points otherwise being too dense close to the center. The uniform distribution of points along that normalized distance is what causes higher density of points near the center.

Comment: the error output says Error using  .* 
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Comment: Do you have an older version of MATLAB? This code assumes implicit singleton expiation, which is new in MATLAB since last year, I believe. I adapted the code to work with older versions that do not have this new feature.

Comment: Until I learned about this trick, I used to generate points uniformly within the bounding box of the ellipse, throwing away points that didn't fall within the ellipse. That is still the correct way to do it for more complex shapes, such as arbitrary polygons.

Comment: yes you are absolutely right, i can see the difference when I choose N = 7000 points, your answer is more accurate, but thanks to all of you

Answer (score 1):

Generate random numbers for x and y axes between the specified limits, i.e. `xRadius` and `yRadius`, for the respective axes. Read [*Random Numbers Within a Specific Range*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/floating-point-numbers-within-specific-range.html) to understand how to generate those random numbers.

```
hold on;
RndAngles = rand(N,1);      %Same angle should be used
Xpoints = (xRadius.*rand(N,1) .*cos(2*pi*RndAngles))+ xCenter;   
Ypoints = (yRadius.*rand(N,1) .*sin(2*pi*RndAngles))+ yCenter;
plot(Xpoints,Ypoints,'o');  %Plot those points
```

***Output:***

[image: Output]

Comment: This produces too many points close to the center of the ellipse. See my answer for a correct distribution of points.